# Modifying the content of a ingested pdf

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a pipeline created in elasticsearch that ingests a document with an array of pdfs. I want to modify the content field in order to concatenate other fields at the end for searching purposes.

My pipeline is:

```
client.ingest.putPipeline({
  id: 'my-pipeline-id',
  body: {
    "description" : "Extract attachment information",
    "processors" : 
    [
      {
        "foreach": {
          "field": "attachments",
          "processor": {
            "attachment": {
              "target_field": "_ingest._value.attachment",
              "field": "_ingest._value.data"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}, callback);
```

I can't add a set processor after the foreach, because I need to access the content of every pdf in order to put the values of that document at the end of the content.

Some example documents are:

```
let doc = {
    matricula: '6789AAA',
    bastidor: 'BASTIDOR789',
    expediente: '79',
    attachments:
    [
        {
            filename: "informe",
            data: /* chunk of data in base64 */
        },
        {
            filename: "ivtm_diba",
            data: /* another chunk of data in base64 */
        }
    ]
};
```

The result document will look like this:

```
{
    "_index": "doc",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "AVsy85rwMuPe74hQBT8L",
    "_score": 1.2039728,
    "_source": {
      "attachments": [
        {
          "filename": "informe",
          "attachment": {
            "Very very long content",
            "date": "2016-06-08T14:01:25Z",
            "content_type": "application/pdf",
            "language": "es",
            "content_length": 3124
          }
        },
        {
          "filename": "ivtm_diba",
          "attachment": {
            "content": "Very long content here",
            "content_type": "application/pdf",
            "language": "ca",
            "content_length": 5657
          }
        }
      ],
      "expediente": "79",
      "matricula": "6789ZXC",
      "bastidor": "BASTIDOR789"
    }
  }
```

And I want to add to the content field the values of "bastidor", "matricula" and "expediente" fields.

I'm using elasticsearch-js but that's not a requirement.

Comment: Hi, you probably know about it, but just in case, isn't _all field enough for what you need? It's already there and you can also customize it. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html. If _all isn't enough then you can create an extra field with the concatenations of the others, basically what you need is to define it in the mapping and use scripting. But I have a feeling the _all field might be enough to what you need(just search).

Comment: Seriously, I don't know why I didn't think about _all but yeah, that is a correct solution to my problem. Thank you!

Please submit your comment as a real answer in order to accept it.

Comment: ok, just posted as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [elasticsearch _all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) can be used in most cases like this.